# Subscript out of bounds in R when trying to make a new list from two seperate data sets using lappy and %in%

Tags: r

I have two data sets, one is a data frame and one is a list. A made up example of my data sets are below:

```
    df <- data.frame(Male=1:4, Female=5:8, Territory=c("TEE","TEE","JEB","GAT"), Year=2013, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      Male Female Territory Year
    1    1      5       TEE 2013
    2    2      6       TEE 2013
    3    3      7       JEB 2013
    4    4      8       GAT 2013

  neighbour <- list()
  neighbour[['GAT']] <- c("TEE","SHY","BOB")
  neighbour[['JEB']] <- c("LEE", "GAT", "BOO")
  neighbour[['TEE']] <- c("DON", "RAZ", "ZAP")

    $GAT
    [1] "TEE" "SHY" "BOB"
    $JEB
    [1] "LEE" "GAT" "BOO"
    $TEE
    [1] "DON" "RAZ" "ZAP"
```

The first data set tells us the ID numbers of the male and females (these are the observed mating pairs- for example, male 1 and female 5 were observed to have mated and the territory they occupy is called TEE), and the territory name that they live in.

This second data set lists the surrounding territories for each territory. For example, territories TEE, SHY, and BOB surround the territory GAT.

What I am trying to do is make a list of potential mates for every female individual based on the territory they live in and the territories that surround the territory they reside in. So I want a list of males in the females territory and the males in the surrounding territory. My end goal is to get something that looks like this:

```
 $`5`
 [1] 1 2

 $`6`
 [1] 1 2

 $`7`
 [1] 3 4

 $`8`
 [1] 1 2 4
```

I was recommended to use this code:

```
 result <- lapply(setNames(nm=df$Female), function(x) {
     #territory of the current female
     FemTer <- df[df$Female == x, "Territory"]
     #males living in the neighbourhood
     df[df$Territory %in% c(FemTer, neighbour[[FemTer]]), "Male"]
     })
```

And it seems like it should work, but for some reason it gives me this error:
      "Error in neighbour[[FemTer]] : subscript out of bounds"

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: I've just run your code and not only there was no error but it produced your output list, as you posted it. There must be something in your workspace, try running it in a new R session.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work and says the same error. There must be something off in my real data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Rui said, I have no problem running your code.
Maybe `df` is not only a `data.frame` (maybe tibble?). Try never to use the accessor `[, j]`, use `[[j]]` instead when manipulating a `data.frame`.

I will give you another approach that may work and that I think is better. This is because for each female in a given territory, you will have the same result. So, I think it would be better to give a result for each territory, not each female.

```
ter_male <- split(df[["Male"]], df[["Territory"]])

ter_male_ext <- lapply(seq_along(ter_male), function(i) {
  ter <- names(ter_male)[[i]]
  ter_ext <- c(ter, neighbour[[ter]])
  sort(unlist(ter_male[ter_ext], use.names = FALSE))
})
names(ter_male_ext) <- names(ter_male)

> ter_male_ext
$GAT
[1] 1 2 4

$JEB
[1] 3 4

$TEE
[1] 1 2
```

Then, to get the result you wanted, you just have to do

```
lapply(split(df[["Territory"]], df[["Female"]]), function(ter) {
  ter_male_ext[[ter]]
})
```

Comment: I get the ter_male_ext list, but when I try to do the last code you mentioned to get what I want, I still get this error: "Error in ter_male_ext[[ter]] : subscript out of bounds". I don't know what it is that isn't working. Thanks so much for helping though! I really appreciate it

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `class(df)`? And the version of R you use.

Comment: the result is data.frame and I use R version 3.4.0

Comment: also, not sure if this says anything but the version of R Studio I'm using is 1.0.143

Comment: Have you tried to begin with a completely clean session and to run only this code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a new R session and I cleared out the work space, but it still doesn't work. Does the error mean that something in df is not found in the ter_male_ext list?

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working! I had to subset my dataframe so that there were unique id's for females because sometimes the females mate with different males in the same territory. This is why it kept saying subscript out of bounds. Also, your code is better because it allows me to consider the males in those situations where the female mates with different males in the same territory in the same year! Thank you so much!!